# How can I use Vue data-bindinding in a Moqui form?

Tags: moqui

I want to add a calculated field to a form that depends on the value entered by the user on some other field and I'd like its value to update before the form is submitted, as if it were using data-binding of some kind.

Is this possible to implement for the vuet output mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While part of the initial Vue JS functionality in Moqui Framework 2.1.0 it is only recently well supported and tested so you will need the latest code from the moqui/moqui-framework and moqui/moqui-runtime repositories. This will all be in the upcoming 2.1.1 release series.

Because this is new and many are likely to have questions about it I added an example and some brief documentation that covers the main differences from normal XML Screens. That is now available on moqui.org here:

https://www.moqui.org/m/docs/framework/User+Interface/Client+Rendered+Vue+Screen

To run this locally you will also need the latest code from the moqui/example repository.